# How to force Devise to use HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, devise, localhost

I have a fresh Rails 5 install with the latest Devise gem. When I have a

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

I get redirected to an SSL version of the sign-in page. When I manually change the URL in the browser to the HTTP version of the sign_in page - the form gets POSTed to the SSL version of the devise session controller.

How can I disable this automatic SSL behaviour for Devise when I am in development mode?

Comment: Please check `config.force_ssl=true` in `config/environments/development.rb` or `config/environments/production.rb`. set this to false.

Comment: I don't have such a setting - and I'd imagine this would apply to all routes? I just don't want devise routes to be forced to SSL - which Devise itself is setting up. As I said this is just a fresh Rails 5 install with Devise gem added - nothing else. Also - I only need this to change for Development - so there wouldn't be any need (or wouldn't have any effect) if I were to change this in production.rb

Comment: Ok. Please provide server log and paste the `config/initializers/session_store.rb` code into question.

Comment: I've found the issue. The Rails app was running in Docker, but I also have another Docker container with nginx that proxies to the Rails app. The nginx.conf file had "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;" set - so all redirects (including the ones that devise generates) get redirected as https.